# Android: Autocad Coordinates are too large

Tags: android, autocad, cad, dxf

I'm working on Autocad files reader for android , now I Only read DXF files using Kabeja library and it works great but when i draw simple shape in Autocad and try to draw it on Android it doesn't appear 
when i look to Autocad coordinates i find them are too large
I have already did a lot of search to find out any solution and one i tried is to read

> EXTMIN and
>   EXTMAX

header values but they return {30=0.0, 20=1015.620062425179, 10=1624.318980044965} for EXTMIN
and {30=0.0, 20=2134.42060268589, 10=3716.108222970341} for EXTMAX

this is my code

```
DXFHeader dxfHeader = dxfDoc.getDXFHeader();
DXFVariable dxfVariableMin = dxfHeader.getVariable("$EXTMIN");
DXFVariable dxfVariableMax = dxfHeader.getVariable("$EXTMAX");
```

i don't know how to use these values to make my shapes be drawn correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EXTMIN and EXTMAX define the area of the dxf drawing that contains geometry (entities).

When displaying a dxf file, you would use the EXTMIN values as an offset.

In your example, the lower-left corner of dxf file area that contains geometry is:

```
1624.318980044965, 1015.620062425179
```

while the upper-right corner is:

```
3716.108222970341, 2134.42060268589
```

This means that your effective canvas size is actually 2091 wide by 1118 tall.

If you had an entity, like a circle, whose x,y center coordinates were 2000,1500; you could then subtract the EXTMIN coords and display the circle at 375.68, 484.38

As long as you subtract the EXTMIN coords from all your entities's x and y coords (10 and 20 group codes) you will be able to display a smaller area that just includes the area that contains geometry.

Comment: that's great now i can see my entities but i have another problem my entities shifted right and above so they don't displayed as i draw them in autocad